# Pass PHP array to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

php file

```
$querySelectWordFilter = "SELECT * FROM badwordfilter";
      $stmtSelectWordFilter = $conn->prepare($querySelectWordFilter);
      $stmtSelectWordFilter->execute();
      while($rowSelectWordFilter = $stmtSelectWordFilter->fetch()){
         $Array[] = $rowSelectWordFilter["filterWord"];
      }

    foreach($Array as $val){
         echo $val;
    }
```

Javascript file

```
<script>
 var filter = ['ass', 'evil','ugly'];
</script>
```

**Question : Firstly,I select all the value from database and store it into array.But how can i pass the PHP array variable into JavaScript filter variable?**

Comment: Just use `var filter = <?php echo json_encode($Array); ?>;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need of foreach loop just create your array

```
while($rowSelectWordFilter = $stmtSelectWordFilter->fetch()){
         $Array[] = $rowSelectWordFilter["filterWord"];
      }
```

And in JavaScript use `json_encode` as

```
<script>
var filter = <?php echo json_encode($Array); ?>;
</script>
```